# using apt-get install in old versions

Tags: apt

Until last week, i could use a Dockerfile that started like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

#Dependencies
RUN apt-get update; 
RUN apt-get install -y git make g++ gcc wget re2c;

(...)
```

But today i ended up with lots of messages like:

```
#0 2.320 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/krb5-locales_1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.2_all.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
```

What is the best way to see if im doing something wrong or if these repos were actually deactivated in the past few days?

Comment: That is an address to a file.  So, you can try downloading that or going to `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/`  in a web browser and searching for that file.  It could be that you just have a temporary Internet problem preventing you to access that site...

Comment: Thanks, indeed i had some kind of wird internet connection that left other web applications run but broke my apt-get. Should i close this question?

Comment: You should answer your own question. Include your troubleshooting to help future folk who have the same problem.

Comment: Good to hear you've solved your problem!  And yes, you should close the question.  Since you figured out the problem yourself, feel free to answer it and accept it.  While I did give you a suggestion, I think it's safe to say that you were the one that solved your problem...I just nudged you in a direction.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ray noted in the comments, the online repository mentioned in the error message was still accessible via browser, so i could reach for it in there.

I had some weird network connection problem which didn't let me access the repo from inside my container. Though i don't know what changed to allow me to access the repo, checking that it was accessible via browser allowed me to understand that the problem was with my network connection, not the repo.

Comment: Usually when someone else solves my problem or helps me solve an issue through a comment, I tell them to put it as an answer and I'll flag it as solved.... just to give them credit for their time. Dunno, seems like the right thing to do to me. I know you mention him in your answer but that doesn't count in his stats. It's all open-source and sharing is caring.